# How can I get the permalink of a page on which shortcode has been used

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I want to redirect users to a page on which a particular short-code has been used after they login. So basically I want to know how can I get the permalink of that particular page on which my plugins specific short code has been used?

Comment: Add some code to clarify your question. I read it twice but still dont understand ur situcation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the very best approach would be to store that page on a option.

Anyway, if you want to get the pages where a shortcode has been used, you can use the search parameter (`s`) of `WP_Query` class (or `get_posts()` function). Basically, this parameter performs a `LIKE` query, so it could be useful to search for shortcodes like this:

```
$args = array(
    's'         => '[myshortcode',
    'post_type' => 'pages'
);

$pages_with_myshortcode = get_posts( $args );
```